# Inventory Promotions/Discount Table Structure

Tags: database-design

I am developing an inventory system and I need help designing a product (items) table, per the below requirements.

1. Some items Have Promotions, like take two items and get one free.
2. The company gives a 2% discount above $100 sale for a single bill.
3. Promotions: if someone purchases 10 packs, the company gives 1 pack, including some units. Also, say if someone purchased 10 cartons of cigarettes (containing 10 boxes of cigarettes) then the company gives 1 carton and 5 boxes of cigarettes free.

My question is how can I handle this? Should I create separate tables for all these types of promotion, or in same table I can handle all of them?

Comment: Use Silverston's Pricing Model in Data Model Resource Book Vol 1.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly what you have described here is behavior and not data storage.  So while, How you store this in the database, is important your primary concern should be how do you write the code for this.

so as an example in c#

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public List<IPromotion> { get; set; }
}

public interface IPromotion {
    decimal CalculateTotalDiscount(Product p, int quantity);
}

public class BuyAndGetFreePromotion : IPromotion  {
    public int QuantityRequiredToGetPromotion { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfUnitsFree { get; set; }

    public decimal CalculateTotalDiscount(Product p, int quantity) {
        if (QuantityRequiredToGetPromotion == quantity) {
            return (p.UnitCost * quantity) - (p.UnitCost * NumberOfUnitsFree );
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now you can do either the table class hierarchy or table per class.  This would depend very much on which ORM you are using, if any.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780132480345/advanced-active-record/ch09lev1sec5#title-ID0EBYHK

As for the question.  I don't believe that the 2% discount would be stored as a Promotion but would rather be the responsibility of the invoice/bill.  Therefore the decision of whether to have multiple tables should instead be based different types of promotions available and whether they can be modelled and stored consistently in a single table.   Do you have more examples of Promotions as currently I would say a single table is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Alistair actually what i need i found from following two site http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/PriceAdm/PriceAdm_ProductPromo5.html                                                                       http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ but I also got idea from your above example thanks so much

Comment: that databaseanswers website is scary and i'm not really sure How a Seibel documentation page is going to help you... except by giving you extra fields to put on the table?